# How to continue a sequence of dates while increasing day by 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know how to continue a sequence of dates:

[image]

In the below picture there are 4 people who have the same date assigned to them. This sequence increases by 1 as the "Nombres" list restarts. Is there an option in excel where I can make it understand that when I drag down I want the next sequence of days to be 2021-03-22,23,24........ Whenever the names list restarts?

Comment: how is the first date decided.  Is it Today, or is it manually put in?

Comment: This is very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695688/add-1-day-to-todays-date-whenever-value-gets-repeated/66696509#66696509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration that your loop remains the same (Rafa, Luis, Fermin, Miguel) you can use this formula to continue, then copy-paste down until the end.

The formula in spanish that you will paste in B3 cell:

> =SI(A3=$A$2;B2+1;B2)

and the same formula in english:

> =IF(A3=$A$2,B2+1,B2)

Just make sure you have at least the first date hardcoded for your first person (in this case, 2021-03-18 for Rafa)

Answer (score 0):

If Nombre is placed on A1, put a initial date in B1 and just below:

```
=SI(A2=$A$2;CONTAR.SI($A$2:A2;A2)-1+$B$1;B1)
```

Then, pull down. It takes the first name as reference to change de date values.